# Does session.getAttribute(str) in Java get stored on the server of client?

Tags: java

I am reviewing some `Java` code where a logged in user object gets stored with the line:

```
session.setAttribute("user", myuser);
```

and later retreived using the line:

```
myuser = session.getAttribute("user");
```

This works as expected, with the `session.getAttribute()` being able to read the saved user. However, I am wondering if this will work if the site is behind a load balancer, and mutliple instances are spinning up and down.

*Are session variables stored on the client?*: in which case, I'd assume a session'ed user object would be accessible across all running instances.

Or *does `session.setAttribute()` store the user object on the server?*: in which case if a user logs in on one instance, then a few page requests later gets bumped to a different running instance, I assume the session'ed user object would *not* be accessible.

Could anyone shed any light on this? Where does session.setAttribute() store it's data?

Comment: No, session variables can not stored on the client! If you store something in client, it'll be a request parameter or a part of body request!

Answer (score 0):

This is how it usually works - after user login, server creates unique SESSION_ID and return it in cookies. Also server creates Session object to store session information (Like session start time, session last activity time, user name etc.). When next request from same user comes - it contains that SESSION_ID in cookies, so server can find appropriate Session object.